# How can I upload Kayaking or Rowing data via a TCX formatted file to Strava?

Tags: flutter, file-upload, upload, strava

I'm recording workouts with a Flutter based mobile application. I can successfully upload bike workouts. https://github.com/BirdyF/strava_flutter/blob/master/lib/Models/activity.dart#L916 lists a pretty wide variety of sports. However I already noticed that "VirtualRide" reverts to a regular bike ride once it is uploaded to Strava.

Now as I'm uploading Kayaking data it also shows up as a bike ride as well (in the middle of a small lake). But at least it has the speed and the rpm (which is actually strokes per minute for kayaking). However if I switch that activity over to Kayaking on Strava's UI Strava stops showing the pace (speed) and the rpm.

I peeked at https://github.com/sanderroosendaal/rowingdata/blob/master/rowingdata/writetcx.py and that seems to output the rowing activities as "Other" sport. Its tests contain such TCXs as well. I just cannot believe TCX would be so limited. Does anyone have a pointer for me to solve this?

I'm outputting TCX because it's a textual format so it's easier to interpolate and debug than a binary FIT format. Since I can gzip it for upload its size is OK as well when compressed.

Comment: So far I'm planning to implement a FIT file export, but that's gonna be way more effort than I'd like to allocate for this nonsensical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that TCX is too limited file format with respect to sport selection. I develop FIT file based upload and that is able to carry Kayaking and many more sports.